# What is the equivalent of 'beforeselect' event for combobox in the ExtJs modern toolkit?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am converting an 7.2 ExtJs application from classic to modern. In the conversion there is a classic combobox that has a '`beforeselect`' event listener and it is checking to see if the user can select the item. If they cannot, the event returns `false` and the item is never selected.

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent in the modern toolkit and I've tried using `onBefore( "select", this.beforeselect, this )` and returning `false`, but it is still selecting the item.

Answer (score 0):

the equivalent is `beforecheckchange`